# NPV of a project

Tags: finance

Consider the following project.

Costs: $100,000, at time t = 0.

$45,000, at time t = 4.

Income: Three payments of $10,000, each one year apart, with the first payment at time t = 1.

Four payments of $60,000, each paid every 4 years apart, with the first payment at time t = 4.5.

a.Write down an equation that you need to solve in order to calculate the internal rate of return for this project.

b.Calculate or state the NPV of this project, at a discount rate that solves the equation you wrote down in (a) above.

---

Part(a) is pretty straight forward. Let NPV = 0. Then I can get my corresponding equations. However; for part (b). Should the NPV equal to 0? Since IRR stnads when NPV = 0.

Comment: I would read (b) as asking you to solve your answer to (a), in order to find the discount rate which makes the NPV $0$.  So, yes